# I don't understand what "driver.find_element_by_..." command I have to use - could someone help me?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I want to investigate the following page: https://jackpot-qr.rewe.de/?c=939393938 and want Selenium to look, if it shows me the red error-code when you press "OK".

This is my code so far, but it never find the code (Im new to python, afaik it only gives me back the "except:"-error message when "try:" didn't work)

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("code_error")
    print("Code failed")
    time.sleep(10)

except:
    print("Didn't work, sorry")
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error did you get exactly? Can you update your question with the error?

Comment: Also, are you trying to get the text of the red error code?

Comment: Additionally, if you catch your exceptions like this, you will never know what error actually happened. You should try `except Exception as e: print(str(e))` for a start to identify what error has actually occurred

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

When you click OK, the element showing the error code does not immediately appear. Thus, we need to wait until it appears before you can proceed with the rest of your code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Other code to initialize driver

# ...

# Click OK button
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/section[1]/div[1]/form/div/button').click()

# Wait till code error appears
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "code__error")))

# Print code error
print(driver.find_element_by_class_name("code_error").text)
```